# necessary condition for the mean value theorem

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Give an example which demonstrates that continuity is a necessary condition for the mean value theorem:

I thought in this function:

$$g(x) = 
\begin{cases}
  x + 1 & x < 1 \\[4pt]
 x - 1 & 1 \leq x\\
 \end{cases}
$$

Clearly $g(x)$ is not continuos in $1$, i try to find the derivative of this function but i stuck some help please for prove that for this function can't use the mean value theorem.

Comment: Pleae reread the statement of the mean value theorem. Especially, for interior points it demands much more than continuity! You can use your $g$ if yuo pick the intervall $[a,b]$ appropriately though)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider your function $g$ on the interval $[0,1]$. Then $g$ is indeed differentiable in $(0,1)$ (with $g'(x)=1$ for all $x\in(0,1)$. The claim of the mean value theorem would say that there exists $c\in(0,1)$ with $g'(c)=\frac{g(1)-g(0)}{1-0}$, i.e. $1=-1$.

Answer (score 1):

For your function, $g(0)=g(2)=1$ so if the mean value theorem applied there would be a point beteen 0 and 2 where the derivative was 0. But the derivative is equal to 1 with left and right limits both equal to 1 at $x=1$. Hence the mean value theorem fails for this discontinuous function.

Comment: On $[0,2]$, the function not only fails to be continuous on $[0,2]$, it also fails to be differentiable on $(0,2)$; so this is not a perfect example

Comment: Good point -- derivative does not exist at x=1, so this is a counterexample for missing both conditions.

Answer (score -1):

Mean value theorem in its usual formulation applies to *differentiable* functions. Which should be at least continuous. If a function is not continuous, then there is no tangent in some points (also, it would be strange to ask fo a derivative in jump point, since there *g(x + Δx)- g(x)* ↛ 0 as Δx→0)